# Create Copy To Clipboard In ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am working an internal ticketing system for IT positions. What I want to know is if there is a way in ColdFusion (CFML/CFScript) that provides the user with the ability to click a button and copy to clipboard. I know in JavaScript that this is a fairly easy thing to do; however, I am not sure if there is a way within ColdFusion to do this without utilizing JavaScript.

What is happening is the system outputs a quick command for logging into remote clients. Instead of making the technician manually copy and paste, it would be a nice/small thing to make a button to automatically copy it for the user.

Comment: Adrian has answered you here, and touches on the technical disconnect you have with your expectations, but it could probably do with expansions. I wrote this blog article years ago because this subject comes up fairly frequently with CFMLers. https://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html. It's vital as a CFML dev to understand the difference between client code and server code, and the request / response lifecycle and the various moving parts. Also: voting to close because it's a non-sequitur of a question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question itself is based on a lack of understanding how the technologies at play work, so doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything CF is a server-side process, so you can't do that. But you can have CF generate the text content of the command. You'd still need a client-side JavaScript function to put that text into the browser's clipboard.

Comment: This was the solution that I ended up implementing. I was not sure if there was any method without utilizing another language.